# What causes the error in a RNN to increase late in training?

Tags: machine-learning, rnn

I'm training a 2-layer, 1024 node, dropout of 0.5 RNN over natural text. Specifically, I'm using [karpathy's char-rnn](https://github.com/karpathy/char-rnn) which I found to work quite well for most of my use cases. Sometimes however, late in the training, my errors drastically increase, and I can't figure out why this is happening.

The question is specifically asking why am I observing the drastic increase in error, and how this is handled in practice. What can be done to prevent this besides taking the last-known good model?

[image]

Comment: Two guesses:
(1) are you shuffling your dataset? Or, are you sampling the data at random for each batch?
(2) the error starts to raise suspiciously close to epoch 40. Do you change your learning rate or other parameters during training? It might be that there is no significant improvement over say 30 epochs and the logic decides to double/half the learning rate,

Comment: @xeon thanks, those are really good suggestions! For 2) I'll dig into the source code to see if there is a change that happens at specific intervals. For 1), I don't think the data is shuffled each batch -- should it be?

Comment: @Hooked What type of optimizer are you using? e.g. SGD, RMSProp, Adam?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause is too high of a learning rate, in particular learning rate schedulers. A relatively high learning rate can cause the model to leave an optimum from earlier training.